# Write "A in bibliography but see" a

Tags: bibliographies, capitalization

I'm writing my bibliography and in a title I wrote the following code:

```
@inproceedings
{
  R14,
  Author = {},
  Booktitle = {},
  Title = {`` A fully integrated..."},
  Year = {}
}
```

But when I see this reference it show like this: "a fully integrated..."
How can I achieve to have "A fully integrated..."?

Comment: The biblography style determines whether titles need capitalization or not.  Your best bet is to use {B}races to {P}rotect things that {N}eed to stay in {C}apitals; e.g.: `title = {``{A} fully integrated...''}`.  (Not sure what is going on with the quotation marks in your example....)

Comment: Great! thanks for your help. That works fine! If you like, post your answer and I will select it as correct. Thanks again

Comment: Whether putting book titles between quotes should be left to the bibliographic style; for instance `amsplain.bst` uses them and in your case you'd end up with *two* pairs of quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bibliography style you choose should be what determines whether and how things like titles should be capitalized.  This helps make the same `.bib` file be reusable in different documents.  However, you need to help things along by protecting things that need to stay capitalized by putting things like proper nouns and acronyms in braces.  In the case of the example above, one approach would be:

```
@inproceedings{R14,
  Author = {},
  Booktitle = {},
  Title = {``{A} fully integrated...''},
  Year = {}
}
```

(I assume the problem in this case is due to the `title` entry starting with a backtick (i.e., `` ` ``) rather than the letter `A`.)

Note also that if you are using `biblatex`, you have more options regarding the use of quotation marks in titles (e.g., `\mkbibquote{...}`).

Answer (score 0):

Building on Jon's answer, I think a slightly easier way to do it is to write something like

```
Title = {{This is your title and it involves CAPITAL letters and NaCl}},
```

is a lot easier to do. Has the exact same effect as individually bracing each capital letter in your title.

Comment: Although this works, it means that your bibliography style will never be able to do the formatting for you.  Thus, if one style expects 'title case' (e.g., This Is a Title about John Smith), while another expects 'sentence case' (e.g., This is a title about John Smith), you would need to edit manually your `title` field because the double braces would (by design) prevent any bibliography style from applying the formatting it is designed to apply.